# PHP Google API OAuth2 JWT request request for access Token says "Invalid JSON payload received"

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

I'm currently working on a project involving Google Cloud API and JWT, and have an issue:

I'm having trouble generating a JWT token to access the Google Cloud API in a Laravel 10 application using the Firebase/php-jwt v6.10.0 package. I get an error when trying to request my access token using the JWT:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message.

My generated JWT is valid as per a validation tool

Here is my code for generating the JWT:

```
    $privateKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEv...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

    $keyId = '4b8eea3586ec09494ccfe2a3718104a5b0ec051c';

    $header = [
        'alg' => 'RS256',
        'typ' => 'JWT',
        'kid' => $keyId
    ];

    $claimSet = [
        'iss' => 'adspy-crawler@ai-tools-414115.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'aud' => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token.',
        'exp' => time() + 60 * 60,
        'iat' => time(),
    ];

    $jwt = JWT::encode($claimSet, $privateKey, 'RS256', $keyId, $header);
```

After generating the JWT, I try to request the access token with:

```
$url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=" . urlencode("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer") . "&assertion=" . $jwt;

Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])->post($url)->json();
```

Attempts to resolve:

I have validated the JWT token I'm generating using an online validation tool. I'm sure I constructed my JSON payload following the Google Cloud API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=en#httprest), but I'm still faced with the error.

Other Context Information

I'm working with the following composer packages in my project:

laravel/framework:v10.43.0

firebase/php-jwt:v6.10.0

Comment: 1) The HTTP request to exchange the JWT Assertion passes the parameters as the request path instead of via the POST body. 2) Change your question's title and remove the error message. Then include the exact error message in your question. The more details you include the easier it is to pinpoint the problem.